# Evaluate an object into a string

Tags: r

I have a string with parameters inside braces, I set these parameters as objects and I want to evaluate them and replace them by their value in my string.

Here is what I did but I don't like the way I did it and maybe I can evaluate my parameters faster.

(I used ls() but I should create a data.frame for my values then I can use them easily).

```
region <- "france"
name <- "julien"

str <- "/test/{region}/v1.1/{name}/{test}"

df <- data.frame(object = gsub("[\\{\\}]", "", regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\{.*?\\}", str))[[1]]), string = unlist(regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\{.*?\\}", str))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
  object   string
1 region {region}
2   name   {name}
3   test   {test}

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df$object[i] %in% ls()){
    df$value[i] <- eval(as.name(df$object[i]))
  } else {
    df$value[i] <- ""
  }
  str <- gsub(df$string[i], df$value[i], str, fixed = TRUE)
}


> df
  object   string  value
1 region {region} france
2   name   {name} julien
3   test   {test}       
> 
> str
[1] "/test/france/v1.1/julien/"
```

If someone have an idea to improve the code and make it more efficient and cleaner (or evaluate directly my parameters in the string), thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you need the data frame, or is the object `str` sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use gsubfn:

```
library(gsubfn)
region <- "france"
name <- "julien"
test <- 'toto'

str <- "/test/{region}/v1.1/{name}/{test}"
gsubfn('\\{(\\w+)\\}', get, str)
[1] "/test/france/v1.1/julien/toto"
```

If you want to pick your variables from a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(region = 'France', name = 'Julien', test = 'Success', 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
gsubfn('\\{(\\w+)\\}', function(x) get(x, df), str)
```

or

```
gsubfn('\\{(\\w+)\\}', x ~ get(x, df), str)
```

or even just:

```
gsubfn('\\{(\\w+)\\}', df, str)
```

It also works with a list:

```
L <- list(region = 'France', name = 'Julien', test = 'Success')
gsubfn('\\{(\\w+)\\}', L, str)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I was looking for. Now I will just find a way to save the values in a data.frame and not in the global env. Thank you !

Comment: Thanks for the data frame way. !

Answer (score 2):

You could use `get` or `mget`, since `eval` is evil. However, a better strategy than having all those objects flying around in your global environment would be creating a look-up table:

```
df1 <- data.frame(object=c("region", "name"),
                  value=c("frace", "julien"))
```

Then you could use `merge`:

```
merge(df, df1, all=TRUE)
```

Comment: I like "`eval` is evil".  Often very true.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to get the values can be achieved by `get` and `exists`:

```
df$value <- sapply(df$object, function(x) if (exists(x)) get(x) else "")

#   object   string  value
# 1 region {region} france
# 2   name   {name} julien
# 3   test   {test}
```

---

An alternative way (without the data frame):

```
str <- "/test/{region}/v1.1/{name}/{test}"

matches <- regmatches(str, 
                      gregexpr("(?<=\\{)\\w+(?=\\})", str, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
values <- sapply(matches, function(x) if (exists(x)) get(x) else "")

for (i in seq_along(matches)) {
  str <- sub(paste0("\\{", matches[i], "\\}"), values[i], str)  
}

str
# [1] "/test/france/v1.1/julien/"
```

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb when dealing with strings is to never, ever use the builtin regular expression functions, if you can help it.  Instead, use the `stringr` package since it makes your code cleaner.

In this case, you can simplify the `gregexpr`/`regmatches` mess with a call to `str_match_all`.
The parentheses, `(`, show the region to be captured: "at least one alphabetic character", via `[[:alpha:]]+`.  This is returned in the second column.
The first column contains the full match, which also includes the curly braces, `{`.

```
library(stringr)
matches <- str_match_all(str, "\\{([[:alpha:]]+)\\}")[[1]]
colnames(matches) <- c("string", "object")
matches
##     string     object  
## [1,] "{region}" "region"
## [2,] "{name}"   "name"  
## [3,] "{test}"   "test"
```

Then proceed as per Roland's answer, using a lookup data frame.

```
lookup <- data.frame(
  object = c("region", "name"),
  value  = c("france", "julien")
)

(df <- merge(matches, lookup, all.x = TRUE))
##  object   string  value
## 1   name   {name} julien
## 2 region {region} france
## 3   test   {test}   <NA>
```

---

Update regarding replacing values:

Since the values need to be updated sequentially rather than all at once, a `for` loop is as good as anything.  There are a couple of minor improvements that you can make. `1:nrow(df)` is a bad idea if it is possible for `df` to have zero rows, since `1:0` is not what you want. `str_replace_all` is a little easier on the eye than `gsub`.

First, a couple of changes to the data frame.  The string column should be a charcter vector rather than a factor, and you want empty strings instead of missing values.

```
df <- within(
  df,
  {
    string <- as.character(df$string)
    value <- ifelse(is.na(value), "", value)   
  }
)
```

The updated loop looks like:

```
str <- "/test/{region}/v1.1/{name}/{test}"

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) 
{
  str <- with(df, str_replace_all(str, fixed(string[i]), value[i]))
}
str
## [1] "/test/france/v1.1/julien/"
```

Comment: Thank for the "best practices". But if I build a data frame this way, what's the "best" way to replace the values in my string.  

`for (i in 1:nrow(df)){  
  str <- gsub(df$string[i], df$value[i], str, fixed = TRUE)  
}`  

I use this loop, but I think there is something better. (I replaced NAs by "" instead it doesn't work for the replacement)